# Taking input from a website and adding it to a C# List

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

So I'm currently learning ASP.net MVC for my work, and I've just been kind of playing with it to learn some things. Currently, I've got a webpage that comes up with a hard coded list from the C# code (simulating a database) and a Create button that brings up an menu, allowing me to add info for a new person and then click the create button at the bottom to add it. However, the create button does not currently work. How do I create a method to take that input and add it to the list, and further more, where should that method go? PersonController? PersonModel? Thanks for the help!

```
    namespace ASPpractice.Controllers
    {
        public class PersonController : Controller
        {

    List<PersonModel> people = new List<PersonModel>();

    // GET: Person
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Person()
    {


        people.Add(new PersonModel {Age = 76, Name = "Rick", Title = "Drunk Mad Scientist"});
        people.Add(new PersonModel {Age = 13, Name = "Morty", Title = "Tool of a Grandson"});
        people.Add(new PersonModel {Age = 35, Name = "Jerry", Title = "Unemployed Dumbass Father"});

        return View(people);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

}

```
    namespace ASPpractice.Models
    {
        public class PersonModel
       {
    private string _Name;
    private string _Title;
    private int _Age;

    public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { this._Name = value; }}
    public string Title { get { return _Title; } set { this._Title = value; } }
    public int Age { get { return _Age; } set { this._Age = value; } }

}
```

}

```
@model ASPpractice.Models.PersonModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

 <h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>PersonModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Person")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your learning experience could really benefit from some tutorials on ASP.NET MVC.  For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started  Essentially you would likely have two `Create` actions.  One would display a view for the user to fill in the values to create the object, and the other would accept the form post of those values and save the newly created object to the database.  Once saved, you would redirect the user back to the index/listing view to see all objects again.

Comment: Ah it looks like this tutorial may be just what I needed. I read through several documentations on msdn for mvc model, but somehow I didn't come across this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Create(){}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PersonModel model)
{
    people.Add(new PersonModel {Age = model.Age, Name = model.Name, Title =model.Title});
    return View();
}
```

Comment: This does not work, although the text I when I fill out the new person's information does not disappear when I click the create button. It just stays there. But when I go back to the list page it does not show the new name.

Comment: try this:
static List<PersonModel> people = new List<PersonModel>();

Comment: Closer...it added it but it also added duplicates of every other item on the list. I don't understand why it being static changed the behavior like this?

Comment: the reason is that a controller is an object ,whenever a request comes to one of its action methods a new instance of that controller is created.

Comment: recall the use of static

Answer (score 1):

**websites are request based**.... so your list which you want to add it to **can not exist within your controller**, as the controller is created e**ach time a action in the controller is requested.**

this would in effect reset your list each time.

You would need to create a *static* list which is accessible from anywhere....

Comment: I see. So since this is for practice, what if I just wrapped the list so that each time the request is made, it clears the list and then recreates it to update it? That way I don't have duplicates. (Again, this is all just for learning purposes, in reality I'll have an SQL server database)

Comment: `it clears the list and then recreates it to update it?` no that doesn't quite make sense. I highly recommend just creating a DB, Look into `Code First`, its so easy with Ms stuff its literally built-in. if you don't  you need to create static class which can persist your `adds/modifcations` across requests. Then you should research a kind of singleton pattern, but i feel you should get the basics first. Learn how to get a Static class which is accessible across request or just implement the DB.

Comment: I did what I had said and it works fine for now. I agree with you though, I need to go back and learn some of this other stuff and get a regular database made. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is call a method in Controller which will populate the list.
On the glance your *EditorFors* should be fine and populate your model correctly.

Using

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod","Controller",FormMethod.Post))
```

will call your ActionMethod where you should accept your *PersonModel*.

```
public ActionResult ActionMethod(PerosnModel vm)...
```

In there you do what you need with submitted model. (ie add it to the db table, post, save or display).

Hope this helps.